# Two simultaneous EXE files running WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, custom-action

I have two custom actions running two EXE files. But they get extracted at the same time and the processes block each other during install. How do I schedule them one after the other?

```
<CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit1"
              FileKey="UMIEXE"
              ExeCommand=""
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="asyncNoWait"
              Impersonate="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="StartAppOnExit1"
            Before="InstallFinalize">$UMIEXE=3</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit2"
              FileKey="Python"
              ExeCommand=""
              Execute="commit"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action ="StartAppOnExit2"
            After="StartAppOnExit1" >$Python=3</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Here is my code, but I seem to be getting an error with what you told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In product.wxs sequence them one after another and in custom action have a check to validate that the exe is executed and hold the process there only

```
<Custom Action="FirstCustomAction" After="InstallFinalize">NOT INSTALLED AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
<Custom Action="SecondCustomAction" After="FirstCustomAction">NOT INSTALLED AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
```

in CustomAction 
`WaitForExit()` in process call.

Comment: Use 'msiexec /i Setup.msi /l*v log.txt' and check log.txt file for specific error.